# Is there a Nokogiri example code for parsing Acrobat XFDF?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, xfdf

I am looking for a ruby code snippet that shows use of Nokogiri to parse Acrobat XFDF data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no different than parsing any other XML:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xfdf = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
  <f href="Demo PDF Form.pdf"/>
  <fields>
    <field name="Date of Birth">
      <value>01-01-1960</value>
    </field>
    <field name="Your Name">
      <value>Mr. Customer</value>
    </field>
  </fields>
  <ids original="FEBDB19E0CD32274C16CE13DCF244AD2" modified="5BE74DD4F607B7409DC03D600E466E12"/>
</xfdf>
'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xfdf)
doc.at('//xmlns:f')['href'] # => "Demo PDF Form.pdf"
doc.at('//xmlns:field[@name="Date of Birth"]').text # => "\n      01-01-1960\n    "
doc.at('//xmlns:field[@name="Your Name"]').text # => "\n      Mr. Customer\n    "
```

It uses a XML namespace, so you have to honor that in the xpaths, or deal with it by telling Nokogiri to ignore them, but this is common in XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[nguyen][1]` gem to do parsing job

```
xfdf = Nguyen::Xfdf.new(:key => 'value', :other_key => 'other value')

# use to_xfdf if you just want the XFDF data, without writing it to a file puts   
xfdf.to_xfdf

# write xfdf file
xfdf.save_to('path/to/file.xfdf')
```